# Find a path with BFS in a graph

Tags: java, graph, path, breadth-first-search

I want to find a path between two nodes in a graph with a bfs. I wrote a function that visit all nodes in the correct order (not sure if it works, but it seems right to me) but I need to store the the path (with a list of all edges that makes the path) and I don't know how to do it :\

Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an array `p`of parents. So if `p[u] = v` there is an edge from `v` to `u` in the path from the source to `u`. Where the parent of the source vertex is `null`.

So when we are in the current vertex `v`, before inserting its adjacent vertex `u` in the queue, we make `p[w] = v`. When you find the destination vertex you go backward in the array p. Starting from the destination vertex `w`, `p[w]` is the parent of `w` and `p[p[w]]` is the parent of the parent of `w` and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to get my function works, I just had to make the array of parents like you said ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the approaches.

In this approach you keep a queue of lists in which you get the list and get the first node from that list.

find the `adj()` of that node and for each node not visited add a new `path+[node]` in the queue , also if the destination is reached return that `path+[node]`.

```
step 1 : create a queue of to hold the paths.
step 2 : add the source as  [ source ] in the queue
step 3 : while the queue is not empty get one path from it
         (as this works for both bfs and dfs thats why "get" not "dequeue" or "pop")

step 4: get the last node of that path (list)
step 5: get the adj of that node and for each not explored create a new path i.e oldpath +[adj node]

step 6:if the adj node is what u want then return the path else add the path to the queue
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, it helped me a lot to have a better understanding of the problem ^^